# An infinity loop during recursive directory search in c#

Tags: c#, recursion, directory, system.io.fileinfo

I'm trying to make a code in c# that prints all file directories in my computer, and I'm almost there. But a problem exists:

When a folder name is just a space (" ") the process goes into an infinite loop.
What do you advise me to do, without changing the folders name or ignoring that?

Comment: It is so very hard to guess without seeing your recursion code.

Comment: Sounds like you have a bug that is caused by your own code. Edit your post and include the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Post your code. There is already existing api in .net that can do this. [See Directory.GetDirectories method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143314(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks everyone. I fixed the problem. I added "\" to the end of all folder directories and it solved my problem.